# Measuring length using Aplpy or Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a contour map of some feature I am studying. I would like to measure the distance between two points that I choose arbitrarily. I could of course just use the coordinates and then work out the hypotenuse but this is tedious and moreover the units are unfriendly. So I wanted to know if there was an interactive tool I could enable in [APLpy](http://aplpy.github.io/) or matplotlib or anything in Python such that I could draw out the line on top of the contour. A bit like in powerpoint where you could draw a line and then stretch it till it matches the length you want but here I would also like to know the length it represents.